# Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, matlab, c#-4.0, deployment

I have created a deployment project in visual studio 2010. I am linking MATLAB components and .NET components.
MY MATLAB is 64 bit and Visual Studio is also 64 bit but some references are 32 bit.

When I compile the deploayment project i get the following warning "Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly".

I tried everything and set my processor to 64 bit.
But still I get the warning.

Comment: What conflicts did you have ?

Comment: What warning it shows?

Answer (score 1):

This means that you reference assembly A ver. xxx in project 1 and assembly A ver. yyy in project 2.

The problem is that you may also reference project 2 from project 1 and so both A may get in conflict when the referenced assemblies are loaded at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this still helps you or not!
I have just faced this problem with some modules provided by a third party company and I have started Googling on this problem now!

As many others have suggested it means some of your modules/dlls use ver.A of another core module and some others use ver.B. In my case all the modules look for MODULE_A_VER_X.(signature XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX) and one looks for the exact same module with the exact same ver but with a different signature [e.g. MODULE_A_VER_X.(signature YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY)]

In your installer project right click on each 'Detected Dependency' and then on the properties window, click on 'Dependencies' Item. It shows you the core modules that a particular module depends on!

Doing so (for all of your dependencies), helps you to identify whats the missing/conflict core module(s) and puts you on the right track.

then you can contact MATLAB to ask them to provide you with the core module with correct version and signature. or you can try finding it yourself.

Then you can try adding that module to your installer project and see if it works or not!
(in my case the third party provider told me it will fix my issue but it did not! maybe for you it works!)

you can also try creating your installer using some packages other than VS installer such as WIX.